# please help me understand this main() code

Tags: c, shellcode

Please could someone help me understand what's going on here. on the main program actually.

```
#include <stdlib.h>

char shellcode[] = "\xbb\x14\x00\x00\x00", "\xb8\x01\x00\x00\x00","\xcd\x00";

int main()
{
    int *ret
    ret = (int *) &ret + 2;
    (*ret) = (int)shellcode;
}
```

Comment: It does not compile because a semicolon is missing after `int *ret` ;-)

Comment: Sems to be a system hack. The program write shellcode bytes to stack and exit main without return instruction, that is undefined behaviour.

Comment: this line (*ret) = (int)shelcode;
why did they have to use the bracket? could they not have written it as 
ret = (int)shellcode;

Comment: Brackets are verbose and useless, but the code could be *ret=(int)shellcode

Comment: we use the *ret when declaring a pointer, 
and then we use the ret = &variable, when assigning an address of a variable to the ret pointer 
and then we use the *ret again when trying to access the value inside the ret pointer... 

am i correct on this ?

Answer (score 2):

First of all some fixes to let the code work:

- Append **;** to line 7 to mark the end of your instruction.
- Remove other strings after the first one in line 3 because this instruction line expects to assign to char variables.

Furthermore `stdlib` isn't required because nothing of it is used, the assignment to `ret` can be skipped by directly using the result in line 8 and your `shellcode` string can be shortened to 3 characters because just 4 bytes are used and C strings end with a termination character anyway.

```
char shellcode[] = "\xbb\x14\x00";

int main()
{
    int *ret;
    *((int*)&ret + 2) = (int)shellcode;
}
```

Compiling this with `gcc -o test.o -c test.c` for x86 target outputs following assembly (with comments by me):

```
Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <_main>:                                           ; int main(){
   0:   55                      push   %ebp                 ; save base pointer on stack
   1:   89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp            ; save current stack in base pointer
   3:   83 e4 f0                and    $0xfffffff0,%esp     ; align stack by 16
   6:   83 ec 10                sub    $0x10,%esp           ; reserve 16 bytes on stack (including <int *ret;>)
   9:   e8 00 00 00 00          call   e <_main+0xe>        ; just move program pointer forward for the following instruction to be aligned
   e:   8d 44 24 0c             lea    0xc(%esp),%eax       ; %eax = &ret
  12:   83 c0 08                add    $0x8,%eax            ; %eax = (int*)%eax + 2
  15:   ba 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%edx            ; %edx = (int)shellcode
  1a:   89 10                   mov    %edx,(%eax)          ; *(%eax) = %edx
  1c:   c9                      leave                       ; restore stack & base pointer from enter
  1d:   c3                      ret                         ; }
  1e:   90                      nop
  1f:   90                      nop

Disassembly of section .data:

00000000 <_shellcode>:
   0:   bb                      .byte 0xbb                  ; char shellcode[] = "\xbb...
   1:   14 00                   adc    $0x0,%al             ; ...\x14\x00...
    ...                                                     ; ...";    (should be the termination character \x00)
```

Assuming the stack alignment does nothing, your 4 `shellcode` bytes get copied on the stack behind `ret` and the saved base pointer, so out of the function scope.
Now thinking about `int main()` is a shortcut for `int main(int argc, char** argv)` leads us to the conclusion: these 4 bytes replace `argv` - the address to the command line string, passed in main, was overridden. But for what?

Comment: wow! this is somewhat overwhelming, but i think the idea was to to overwrite the eip to point to the shell-code or something, I'm having problem studying assembly because i'm on x86_64 Linux, and there's hardly a good book to give me hands-on tutorial